# How to equally share resources between users on multiple levels

Tags: python, algorithm, resources

Issue:
There are a number of limited jobs that can be processed at one time. There are multiple users that share these resources (workers) and at this moment there is no algorithm to share resources in an equal fashion.

Example:
There are 8 workers and 4 users from 4 teams, which in this order made a request for 10 jobs each. At this moment, the processing is done as FIFO, and the first users will take all the workers, the others having to wait for a long time. The users are split into teams.

My solution so far:
1. Each team can have a maximum of 1/(no_of_teams_with_jobs)*100% (eg as above, 1/4*100 = 25%. So each team has 25% of available slots (8), which means 2. 
2. The 2 slots will be then equally shared between team members.

```
  _________________________________________________________________________________________
  | Worker 1 | Worker 2 | Worker 3 | Worker 4 | Worker 5 | Worker 6 | Worker 7 | Worker 8 |
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |      Project 1      |      Project 2      |      Project 3      |      Project 4      |
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 |  User 1  |  User 1  |  User 2  |  User 2  |  User 3  |  User 3  |  User 4  |  User 4  |
1 |  User 1  |  User 1  |  User 2  |  User 2  |  User 3  |  User 3  |  User 4  |  User 4  |
2 |  User 1  |  User 1  |  User 2  |  User 2  |  User 3  |  User 3  |  User 4  |  User 4  |
3 |  User 1  |  User 1  |  User 2  |  User 2  |  User 3  |  User 3  |  User 4  |  User 4  |
```

So the line 0 can be already running jobs and the rest of the lines can be pending jobs. I arranged them like this so each of them will receive a ticket_number from left to right, from 1 to n, which means the order in which will receive the first empty slot.

The second number they will receive is the line they are on, because i need to compute an estimate of the duration. If you are on line 2, then probably you will wait for 2 jobs to complete.

Basic example of code:

```
jobs = load_jobs()
jobs = compute_priority_and_estimate(jobs) # job.priority=x, job.estimate=seconds
persist_jobs_in_db(jobs)
```

Then in a separate process

```
jobs_to_process = load_jobs_to_process(free_slots=10) # order by job.priority ASC, limit 10
```

I think the approach is correct, but the implementation is a bit messy and i am looking for a simpler approach or an algorithm that can keep the code clean.

EDIT: The question is if there is any kind if existing implementation or algorithm of a similar idea that i can inspire from.

I hope i expressed the problem as clearly as possible.

Comment: @Georgy Hi, I started to write the code and then i realized is complicated and i tried to find another way. The question is more directed to how i should approach the problem and then i will find a way to implement it into code. Does this help ?

Comment: @Georgy i added the tag because i think people should know the limitations of the language i am using. If i use PHP and i don't have threads there can be another approach etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure exactly what the question is so I'm just going to throw out a couple of idea. I think you're on the right track with queues.

If you want to ensure that the scheduler fairly selects work from across the teams you could have a queue per team. In terms of implementation you would need a thread per team queue that takes items off the team queue and puts it onto a shared queue that has a max size of one that the scheduler takes work from.

If on the other hand you want to fairly balance work across teams over all time you could use a priority queue and separate counter per team. Whenever an item is added to the queue you take the next number from the team's counter and use that for the priority. This would mean that if you introduce a new team that produces a lot of work it would hog the scheduler until it's counter catches up with the other teams.

Comment: If either of those sound like what you need let me know and I'll try to put together some example code.

Comment: Hi, i edited my question to be more specific on the approach. Basically i save in the database the calculations on priority and then i load them sorted by that number. This allows me to scale whenever i need to. Also, i don't have a queue, i take the jobs from the database.  The behavior that i want, is that if another team has jobs, they will get their fair share of the total number of workers.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Those two approaches still apply; either balancing the work currently in the queue across teams or balancing the total amount of work done for each team. The fact that you're using a database for your queue just changes the implementation. Are you asking how to implement one of these approaches with SQL or are you asking for a different approach?

Comment: I think our approaches are similar. In code i was thinking like this: jobs[project][user] = [job1, job2] etc. But processing like this it takes a lot of loops. I understand correctly? My best hope is that i find an implementation on a similar issue.